# How to test background jobs (Sidekiq) with Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, background-process, stub, sidekiq

A large part of my application relies on background jobs to process user's websites, so I need to write some tests to cover these.

First question is how to test code that's in a [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) worker class, for example `app/workers/some_worker.rb`

```
class SomeWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(model_id)
    ...
  end
end
```

Secondly, how do I stub code such as the following so I don't need to actually run workers and slow down my tests?

```
response = HTTParty.get("http://users-site.com", timeout: 30)
```

Answer (score 15):

Read the [Testing page in the Sidekiq wiki](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing).

Comment: Woops I missed that, I see I can use `work = HardWorker.new; work.perform(1, 2)` to run the code. Still not sure how to go about faking external sites for the tests though.

Comment: [Aforementioned Sidekiq wiki page on testing](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing).

Comment: @mind.blank have a look at [VCR](https://github.com/vcr/vcr) for stubbing your API calls

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the [rspec-sidekiq](https://github.com/philostler/rspec-sidekiq) gem I've authored to do exactly this (testing of Sidekiq workers).

Answer (score 3):

Sidekiq provides a few options for testing your workers

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Testing

For me it worked after I  add these lines at the top of a spec-file

```
require 'sidekiq/testing'
Sidekiq::Testing.inline!
```